# FLUTTER ERROR: Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter_downloader/src/downloader.dart'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, download, flutter-dependencies

I've a flutter program which downloads a file by using a URL using the [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) package.I hace a button where on click will download the file.

Below is my implementation

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
 import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
 import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

  void main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await FlutterDownloader.initialize(
     debug: true 
    );
    runApp(MyApp());
   }

   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return MaterialApp(
         title: 'Flutter Demo',
         theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
           home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page',key: GlobalKey(),),
         );
          }
         }

        class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
            MyHomePage({required Key key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
              final String title;
               @override
              _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
             }

       class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
         @override
         Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
           ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 60,),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("Start Downloading"),
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () async {
            final status = await Permission.storage.request();

            if (status.isGranted) {
              final externalDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

              final id = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/storage-3cff8.appspot.com/o/2020-05-29%2007-18-34.mp4?alt=media&token=841fffde-2b83-430c-87c3-2d2fd658fd41",
                savedDir: externalDir!.path,
                fileName: "download",
                showNotification: true,
                openFileFromNotification: true,
              );


            } else {
              print("Permission deined");
            }
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

The error massage I get when the button is pressed is,

```
E/flutter (21960): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 
'package:flutter_downloader/src/downloader.dart': Failed assertion: line 80 pos 12: 
'_initialized': FlutterDownloader.initialize() must be called first
 E/flutter (21960): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core- 
 patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
 E/flutter (21960): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core- 
 patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
 E/flutter (21960): #2      FlutterDownloader.enqueue 
 (package:flutter_downloader/src/downloader.dart:80:12)
 E/flutter (21960): #3      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> 
 (package:care_giver_app/functions_test.dart:102:54)
  E/flutter (21960): <asynchronous suspension>
  E/flutter (21960):
```

If im not wrong,it states that I have to initialize flutter_downloader first but I've already done that in line No.06-No.09 in the implementation above.

I've provided the necessary providers in the AndroidManifest file as well

```
<provider
       android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
       android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
       android:exported="false"
       android:grantUriPermissions="true">
       <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
           android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
   </provider>
   <provider
       android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
       android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
       android:exported="false"
       tools:node="merge">
       <meta-data
           android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
           android:value="androidx.startup"
           tools:node="remove" />
   </provider>

   <!-- declare customized Initializer -->
   <provider
       android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.FlutterDownloaderInitializer"
       android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter-downloader-init"
       android:exported="false">
       <!-- changes this number to configure the maximum number of concurrent tasks -->
       <meta-data
           android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS"
           android:value="5" />
   </provider>
```

Comment: Remove debug: true, just write :  await FlutterDownloader.initialize( );